# Why In redux Output is coming like this --> State Changed{}

Tags: redux

I am learning redux with simple age Increment and Decrement example here is the code

```js
const { createStore } = require(`redux`);


const initialState = {age: 21};

const reducerOne = (state = initialState, action) => {
    const newState = {...state};
    if(action.type === `ADD`) {
        newState.age = action.value;
    }
    if(action.type === `SUBTRACT`) {
        newState.age = action.value;
    }
    return newState;
}

const store = createStore(reducerOne);

store.subscribe(() => {
    console.log(`State Changed` + JSON.stringify(store.getState()));
})

store.dispatch({type: `ADD`, val: 10});
store.dispatch({type: `SUBTRACT`, val: 5});
```

But in Output it is showing like this -->  State Changed{}
Help how to fix this and to get Output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your action is posting the `val` property and your reducer is reading the `value` property.

Change your actions this way and it will work:

```js
store.dispatch({type: `ADD`, value: 10});
store.dispatch({type: `SUBTRACT`, value: 5});
```

EDIT:

You are replacing your old `age` value, but probably you want to add or subtract from it. You have to modify your reducer to achieve such behaviour:

```js
const reducerOne = (state = initialState, action) => {
    const newState = {...state};
    if(action.type === `ADD`) {
        // add to the previous `age` value and do not overwrite it
        newState.age = state.age + action.value;
    }

    if(action.type === `SUBTRACT`) {
        // subtract from the previous `age` value and do not overwrite it
        newState.age = state.age - action.value;
    }
    return newState;
}
```

Comment: Hi @lavor I tried what you said but  there is no change.

Comment: @Shiva you are doing something wrong. I just copied the code you pasted here, changed `val` to `value` as I wrote here above and I can see 2 lines in console log. `State Changed{"age":10}` and `State Changed{"age":5}`

Comment: Now it's working for me also in console it is showing State Changed{'age': 10} State Changed{'age':5}. But my expected output is State Changed{'age':31} and State Changed{'age':16} According to logic it has to show this output. But why it is showing different?

Comment: No, according to your code the console log is correct. You are overwriting the value of `age` with the value of  `action.value`. I understand now what are you trying to achieve, see my edit.

Comment: The correct output will be then `State Changed{'age':31}` and `State Changed{'age':26}` and not `State Changed{'age':31}` and `State Changed{'age':16}`